# For a HttpGet method what are getParams()?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

```
org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;

HttpGet method = new HttpGet(url.toExternalForm());
method.getParams()
```

Whare are these params?  Are they the query string?  there seems to be no easy way to add a query string with org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the [Http Client tutorial](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html), you can do this:

```
URI uri = new URIBuilder()
        .setScheme("http")
        .setHost("www.google.com")
        .setPath("/search")
        .setParameter("q", "httpclient")
        .setParameter("btnG", "Google Search")
        .setParameter("aq", "f")
        .setParameter("oq", "")
        .build();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(uri);
System.out.println(httpget.getURI());
```

Answer (score 0):

These parameters are the HTTP GET request parameters.

For instance in the URL *http://www.mysite.com/login?username=mcjones*, the parameter username has value mcjones.

Answer (score 0):

From http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpMethodBase.html#getParams%28%29 :

> getParams
>
> public HttpMethodParams getParams()
>
> ```
> Returns HTTP protocol parameters associated with this method.
>
> Specified by:
>     getParams in interface HttpMethod
>
> Returns:
>     HTTP parameters.
> Since:
>     3.0
> See Also:
>     HttpMethodParams
> ```

The full list of parameters for the request can be found at http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/params/HttpMethodParams.html

Comment: The question is about httpclient 4.x, your answer is about 3.x.